# Invalid policy role JSON

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I am following this tutorial:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-cli-tutorial-fargate.html

the json for a policy is as shown:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

but when I run:

```
aws iam --region us-west-2 create-role --role-name ecsTaskExecutionRole --assume-role-policy-document task-execution-assume-role.json
```

I get:

> An error occurred (MalformedPolicyDocument) when calling the
>   CreateRole operation: This policy contains invalid Json

I know the filepath is right, because if it's wrong I get a different error. At first I thought it was "invalid json" because "sid" is an empty string, I removed that property and got the same error.

anyone know what's wrong here?

Comment: Like thousands (?) of AWS new starters, I also didn't expect `file://` to be mandatory.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You need to specify the `assume-role-policy-document` as `file://task-execution-assume-role.json`.

From the documentation you linked

> aws iam --region us-west-2 create-role --role-name ecsTaskExecutionRole --assume-role-policy-document file://task-execution-assume-role.json

it's not a very intuitive error that the cli throws because of the missing `file://`...

```
aws iam --region us-west-2 create-role \
--role-name ecsTaskExecutionRole \
--assume-role-policy-document task-execution-assume-role.json

An error occurred (MalformedPolicyDocument) when calling the CreateRole operation: This policy contains invalid Json
```

With the added `file://` the create goes through

```
aws iam --region us-west-2 create-role \
--role-name ecsTaskExecutionRole \
--assume-role-policy-document file://task-execution-assume-role.json
{
    "Role": {
        "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
            "Version": "2012-10-17",
            "Statement": [
                {
                    "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
                    "Effect": "Allow",
                    "Principal": {
                        "Service": "ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "RoleId": "AROA2ZHAP3GUV5UTOV5ZF",
        "CreateDate": "2019-07-31T23:15:04Z",
        "RoleName": "ecsTaskExecutionRole",
        "Path": "/",
        "Arn": "arn:aws:iam::*******:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have the file in the same folder you can execute it as follows.

```
aws iam create-role --role-name TestRole --assume-role-policy-document file://./IAM_Trust_Policy.json --profile XXX-XXX
```

Here the file **IAM_Trust_Policy.json** is located in the same folder and being referred as **file://./IAM_Trust_Policy.json**

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is not clearly documented - you need to provide the file path to the json AFTER the `file://` tag

For example `file:///Users/user/Desktop/trust-policy.json`

Answer (score -2):

{
"Id": "Policy1650533705078",
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
{
"Sid": "Stmt1650533484709",
"Action": [
"s3:GetObject"
],
"Effect": "Allow",
"Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mys3staticwebstiehosting/*",
"Principal": "*"
}
]
}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).